# Rails: Link to sub directory within images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I'm seeding some items into my app. The item photos are kept under items sub directory like so: `assets/images/items/1.jpg`

I want to do something like:

```
all_images.each do
   item = Item.new(photo: "1.jpg")
end
```

So that I can reference my items in rails views like `image_tag(some_item.photo)`

But right now, the url "avatars/1.jpg" is showing up as broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `Dir`?

`all_images = Dir.entries(Dir.pwd + "/app/assets/images")` ?

Also it looks like you'll need the full path starting with `/assets/` for each photo to show up.

**Updated Answer:**

You are using the path `/assets/images/avatars/1.jpg` when it should be `/assets/avatars/1.jpg`. The `images` portion should be removed when referring to the image in rails

Comment: I'm able to iterate through all the images okay, but for some reason I can't get the actual image to show in a view. i.e. "background-image:url(assets/images/avatars/1.jpg)"  does not give me anything

Comment: that's CSS, so do you have that within whatever html tag you used like `style="background-image:url(assets/images/avatars/1.jpg)" `?

Comment: I think you're missing the `/` before assets. It should be `background-image:url(/assets/images/avatars/1.jpg) `

Comment: Sorry. To clarify, I have <div class="item" style="background-image:url(assets/images/avatars/1.jpg)">
        </div>  and it's not showing any image

Comment: You're missing the `/` there before assets it should be `<div class="item" style="background-image:url(/assets/images/avatars/1.jpg)"> </div> `

Comment: <div class=item" style="background-image:url(/assets/images/avatars/1.jpg)">
        </div>  also showing no image :(

Comment: Does it need to go under public or something? Wondering if the 1.jpg filename is getting scrambled in assets precompiling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96616/discussion-between-jayem-and-jackson-cunningham).